# Angular filter pipe doesn´t work

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Im working with angular 5 and angular material2, im trying to filter a list of element in the `*ngFor` like you can see here:

```
<div class="book" *ngFor="let book of documents |
 docCategory: fitleredCategories | sortBy: sortvalue : asc">
```

now the second filter is working but first one is not.

**pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'docCategory'
})
export class DocCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let filtered = [];
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }

    filtered = value.filter((doc) => args.includes(doc.categories[0]));

    if (args.length === 0) {
      return value;
    } else {
      return filtered;
    }
  }

}
```

Here is a group of checkbox that on click push the value into `fitleredCategories` array:

**library.component.html**

```
<li class="category" *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <mat-checkbox value="{{category.name}}" (click)="toggleCatInArray(category.name)">{{category.name}}</mat-checkbox>
</li>
```

the `toggleCatInArray` only check if the value exist or not on the fitleredCategories to push it or remove it.

but for some reason the pipe is not working.

**library.component.ts**

```
public fitleredCategories: any = [];

  public toggleCatInArray(category): void {
    this.toggleInArray(category, this.fitleredCategories);
  }
```

i don´t receive any error on the console or something, it just doesn´t filter the `*ngFor`

Comment: which pipe is not working

Comment: the first one `docCategory`

Comment: dont you think is weird that the docCategory pipe is returning the original value argument when the same isnt null?

Comment: @MiguelAngelFrias You're not assigning `value` to anything after filtering it. It should be `value = value.filter(...)`

Comment: correct me if Im wrong, but if you are mutating the filteredCategories array angular might not re execute the pipe line...

Comment: in which part are the filtered Categories are been mutated...?

Comment: in toggleCatInArray

Comment: mmmmmm in that case yes im adding new elements to the array according if the user check or uncheck one of the checkbox, but if im not wrong the pipe should work passing the `filteredCategories` to make the filter

Comment: @MiguelAngelFrias take a look at my answer

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks for the answer i will test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by 2 reasons:

**Bad implementation of the DocCategoryPipe:**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'docCategory'
})
export class DocCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], categories: string[]): any[] {
    if (!value || !categories) {
      return [];
    }

    return value.filter((doc) => args.includes(doc.categories[0]));
  }
}
```

**Mutation of the filteredCategories array:**

In order to re run the pipe in the template, new values/object references need to be passed as arguments. Angular wont re evaluate a pure pipe when you mutate one of its arguments.

To solve this, refactor your code as follows:

```
 <li class="category" *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <mat-checkbox [value]="category.name" (change)="toggleCategory($event)">{{category.name}}</mat-checkbox>
</li>

import {MatCheckboxChange} from '@angular/material';

filteredCategories: string[] = [];
toggleCategory(event: MatCheckboxChange){
  const category = event.source.value;
  if(event.checked){
     this.filteredCategories= [...this.filteredCategories, category];
  }else{
     const matchIndex = this.filteredCategories.indexOf(category);
     this.filteredCategories= this.fitleredCategories.splice(matchIndex,1).
  }
}
```

As you are now setting `filteredCategories` with a new object reference every time that you add/remove categories, angular will re evaluate the pipeline in your template.

Comment: Updated with some further perf. improvements

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to combine pipes like

```
<div class="book" *ngFor="let book of (documents | docCategory: fitleredCategories) | sortBy: sortvalue : asc">
```

And method `filter` doen't filtered current array. It's return a new array. Try this code:

```
... 
return value.filter((document) => ...)
```